# search the dictionary for more data

Tags: python

I created this script I tried various things here and nothing helped so I would like to contact you as more experienced people

basically the script principle what does it do?

the code I put here does this

input

```
1:1:1
```

output

```
1:1:1 this is text from file
```

it works great but if i want to search for two results so it doesn't work here i try it in several ways

the problem is that I want to look for two things at the same time

input `1:1:1 === 4:1:2===0---0`
I'll do a split here

```
split ("===") [0]
split ("===") [1]
split ("===") [2]
```

and the output I'm looking for is

```
1: 1: 1 this is text from file 4: 1: 2 this is next text resolut 0 --- 0
```

from the file from which it takes data looks something like this

"numberssearch.txt"

```
1:1:1===4:1:2===0---0
1:1:1===4:2:3===-1----1
1:1:1===4:3:4===-2----2
1:1:1===4:4:5===-3----3
1:1:1===4:5:6===-4----4
1:1:1===4:6:7===-5----5
```

and this is what the file from which it takes data looks like

"book.txt"

```
1:1:1   text1
1:1:2   text2
1:1:3   text3
1:1:4   text4
1:1:5   text5
1:1:6   text6
1:1:7   text7
ect...
```

this is code

```
with open ("numberssearch.txt") as f:
         unsolved = set (f.read (). split ())
for unsolved_elem in unsolved:
    userinput = unsolved_elem
    file =  open("book.txt",encoding='ISO-8859-1')
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        unsolved_elem = unsolved_elem.split("===")[0]
        if len(words) > 0 and unsolved_elem == words[0]:
           print(line, file=open(""+str("solved")+".txt", "a",encoding='ISO-8859-1'))
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you could read file `"book.txt"` only once and keep on list. And you could `split('===')` onlu once - before `for`-loop and resuse it.

Comment: @furas the code for finding one number works well but I don't know how to edit it to look for two that's the problem  `for item in zip(t1,t2):
`(' '.join([line.strip() for line in item])`)    this doesn't work  because they would have to run two such scripts at the same time, but that didn't work for me either

Comment: @furas I've tried something here already, I'm doing something wrong or I don't know

Comment: @furas for in another added to the file 7000 same results: D

Comment: you may need two `for`-loops - `for line in lines:` -  first to check only first number, second to check only second number. And this can be faster if you load file `"book.txt"` only once - at start.

Comment: or you may use one loop and check line with both values in `unsolved_elem` and set some variables `found1 = True`, `found2 = True` and after loop check if you found both,

Comment: frankly all code could be simpler if you would read `book.txt` only once and keep it as dictionary `{"1:1:1": "text1", ...}` - because this would need only to check `book_dir.get("1.1.1")` to get `text1` (or `None`) - and this doesn't need all this `for`-loop

Comment: if you have the same number many times then how do you choose which text to display? And if you display all possible values then maybe you should keep all as lists `{"1:1:1": ["text1", "other_text", ...} `

Comment: maybe code works fast but it is hard to work with this code and make modyfications.

Comment: @furas it's basically enough as it is now I thought just to split and text the text in the file and search for it twice `4:14:15===-13----13===1:1:1 test `    and the second time it projects the same code and make the output as they need

Comment: for you it is enough, but for me it is so ugly code so I can't work with it - and first what I would do is to recreate it :)

Comment: @furas yes it's true I'm new to programming: D and I'm not very good at it: D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would need to run two nested loops - and it would need to read from file `book` in  two loops - so it would be better first to read data `book.txt` and create dictionary.

---

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and run it.
But you should use `open()`

In this version I assumed that `book` may have the same number many times so it needs list to keep all text for this number.

```
book_txt = '''1:1:1   text1
1:1:2   text2
1:1:3   text3
1:1:4   text4
1:1:5   text5
1:1:6   text6
1:1:7   text7
4:2:3   other3
4:2:4   other4
4:4:5   other5'''

import io

# --- read book.txt ---

book = {}

#with open("book.txt") as f:
with io.StringIO(book_txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        number, text = line.strip().split(" ", 1)
        if number not in book:
            book[number] = []
        book[number].append(text)
        
for item in book.items():
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
('1:1:1', ['text1'])
('1:1:2', ['text2'])
('1:1:3', ['text3'])
('1:1:4', ['text4'])
('1:1:5', ['text5'])
('1:1:6', ['text6'])
('1:1:7', ['text7'])
('4:2:3', ['other3'])
('4:2:4', ['other4'])
('4:4:5', ['other5'])
```

And similar with file `numberssearch.txt` - first I would read all line and run `split('===')`

```
numberssearch_txt = '''1:1:1===4:1:2===0---0
1:1:1===4:2:3===-1----1
1:1:1===4:3:4===-2----2
1:1:1===4:4:5===-3----3
1:1:1===4:5:6===-4----4
1:1:1===4:6:7===-5----5'''

import io

# --- read numberssearch.txt ---

unsolved = set()

#with open ("numberssearch.txt") as f:
with io.StringIO(numberssearch_txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = tuple(line.strip().split('==='))
        unsolved.add(parts)

for item in unsolved:
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
('1:1:1', '4:5:6', '-4----4')
('1:1:1', '4:4:5', '-3----3')
('1:1:1', '4:1:2', '0---0')
('1:1:1', '4:3:4', '-2----2')
('1:1:1', '4:6:7', '-5----5')
('1:1:1', '4:2:3', '-1----1')
```

And later I would search numbers from `book` in `unsolved`

```
for number1, number2, rest in unsolved:

    if (number1 in book) and (number2 in book):

        # nested loops which use `book`
        for text1 in book[number1]:
            for text2 in book[number2]:
                print(number1, text1, number2, text2, rest)
```

Result:

```
1:1:1 text1 4:4:5 other5 -3----3
1:1:1 text1 4:2:3 other3 -1----1
```

---

Full working code:

**EDIT:** I added changes from comments.

```
# files with empty lines
book_txt = '''1:1:1   text1
1:1:2   text2
1:1:3   text3

1:1:4   text4
1:1:5   text5
1:1:6   text6
1:1:7   text7

4:2:3   Hello World 1
4:2:4   Hello World 2
4:4:5   Hello World 3'''

numberssearch_txt = '''1:1:1===4:1:2===0---0
1:1:1===4:2:3===-1----1

1:1:1===4:3:4===-2----2
1:1:1===4:4:5===-3----3

1:1:1===4:5:6===-4----4
1:1:1===4:6:7===-5----5'''

import io

# --- read book.txt ---

book = {}

#with open("book.txt") as f:
with io.StringIO(book_txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            parts = line.split(" ", 1)
            if len(parts) == 2:            
                number, text = parts
                text = text.strip()
                if number not in book:
                    book[number] = []
                book[number].append(text)

for item in book.items():
    print(item)

# --- read numberssearch.txt ---

unsolved = set()

#with open ("numberssearch.txt") as f:
with io.StringIO(numberssearch_txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            parts = tuple(line.split('==='))
            if len(parts) == 3:
                unsolved.add(parts)

for item in unsolved:
    print(item)

# --- search ---

for number1, number2, rest in unsolved:

    if (number1 in book) and (number2 in book):

        for text1 in book[number1]:
            for text2 in book[number2]:
                print(number1, text1, number2, text2, rest)
```

---

If `book.txt` may have every number only once then code can be simpler.

**EDIT:** I added changes from comments.

```
# files with empty lines
book_txt = '''1:1:1   text1
1:1:2   text2
1:1:3   text3

1:1:4   text4
1:1:5   text5
1:1:6   text6
1:1:7   text7

4:2:3   Hello World 1
4:2:4   Hello World 2
4:4:5   Hello World 3'''

numberssearch_txt = '''1:1:1===4:1:2===0---0
1:1:1===4:2:3===-1----1

1:1:1===4:3:4===-2----2
1:1:1===4:4:5===-3----3

1:1:1===4:5:6===-4----4
1:1:1===4:6:7===-5----5'''

import io

# --- read book.txt ---

book = {}

#with open("book.txt") as f:
with io.StringIO(book_txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            parts = line.split(" ", 1)
            if len(parts) == 2:            
                number, text = parts
                text = text.strip()
                book[number] = text

for item in book.items():
    print(item)

# --- read numberssearch.txt ---

unsolved = set()

#with open ("numberssearch.txt") as f:
with io.StringIO(numberssearch_txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            parts = tuple(line.split('==='))
            if len(parts) == 3:
                unsolved.add(parts)

for item in unsolved:
    print(item)

# --- search ---

for number1, number2, rest in unsolved:
    if (number1 in book) and (number2 in book):
        text1 = book[number1]
        text2 = book[number2]
        print(number1, text1, number2, text2, rest)
```

Comment: you are right - text may have also some spaces and it may need to split on first space.

Comment: it can be similar to your previous comment - `number, text = line.strip().split(" ", 1)` - I add `strip()` to remove `\n` at the end of line

Comment: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` sory for problems the text is of various lengths and I have other characters, what should I remove? all empty rows are deleting i used a script and not working

Comment: maybe first use `print( line )` before `split` to see what you really have in variable. maybe it is empty line - and then you should first use `line = line.strip()` and `if line: ... code ....` to run code only when line is not empty. OR maybe this line has only number without text - and it may need to use `parts = line.split(" ", 1)` and check `if len(parts) == 2: ... code ...`

Comment: yes this now working for me thanx :D           `for line in f:
        if not line:
            continue
        parts = line.split(" ", 1)
        if len(parts) == 2:
            number, text = line.strip().split(" ", 1)
        if number not in book:
            book[number] = []
        book[number].append(text)`

Comment: better first use `line = line.strip()` because if you will have empty line between other lines then `line` will have `'\n'` and `if not line:` will not skip this line.

Comment: if you already have `parts` then you can use `numer, text = parts` instead of use again `split(" ", 1)`

Comment: I added all changes in full versions in answer.

Comment: thanx for you time you same ve more more days :D